# In Nuke, how do I get the index of a specific user knob with python?

Tags: python, nuke

For what I found on the web I am not sure if this is possible but I'll ask anyway.

I would like to be able to retrieve the index of a user_knob I previously add via python within my properties panel.

I have a Nuke node to which I added 2 User Tabs (A and B). In the Tab A, I want to be able to insert and remove user_knob with Python when the user clicks on a button. I understand that in order to do that I have to remove all the user_knob from the point where I want to insert the new user_knob, add the new user_knob then put back all the other user_knob after that.

My issue is that I cannot retrieve the index position of the user_knob I would like to take as a starting point so I know from which index I need to run the removeKnob loop.

I have the list of all user knob types and there respective ID number so I know that #1 is for a string, #4 for a pulldown choice menu, #22 for a PyScript Button, #20 for a Tab, etc...

When I look at the node's plain text in a text editor I can see the logic :
*`addUserKnob {20 new_custum_tab l Name of New Tab}`*

I can also access a user knob using its index position within the property panel, so if I want to access the 35th knob (which for instance is a PyScript Button named 'pyscript_button_01') I would go with :

```
node = nuke.selectedNode()

user_knob_index_position = 35
knob_35th = node.knob(user_knob_index_position)

print knob_35th.name()

>>> Result: pyscript_button_01
```

But I don't know how to reverse it. I would like to be able to do :

```
node = nuke.selectedNode()

user_knob_name = "pyscript_button_01"
user_knob = node.knob(user_knob_name)
user_knob_index_position = node.getIndex(user_knob)

print user_knob_index_position

>>> Result: 35
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: cant you store the index value during creation of the panel, and refer to it from that? I think you're right that there's no way to get the "index" of a knob in order, since all knobs are just added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`node.numKnobs()` returns the amount of knobs stored in a node.
You can the iterate and retrieve the index, thus the name of your knob :

```
for index in range(node.numKnobs()):
    if 'your name' in node.knob(index).name():
        print index
```

using  list comprehension:

```
[index for index in range(node.numKnobs()) if 'your name' in node.knob(index).name()]
```